# Why is the Symbol.iterator only returning the value property instead of returning both done and value property

Tags: javascript

I came across a confusion when learning about **[Symbol.iterator]**. I am using a trial object named num which is a object with key *from* and *to*. In order to run for..of with objects i used [Symbol.iterator] but i had a little confusion. When i try to run the code it only returns the value instead of returning the whole {done:true, value:this.the object value}.

Here is the code the used and it is from JavaScript.info

```
let num = {
  from: 1,
  to: 5,

  [Symbol.iterator]() {
    return {
      current: this.from,
      last: this.to,
      next() {
        if (this.current <= this.last) {
          return {
            done: false,
            value: this.current++
          };
        } else {
          return {
            done: true
          };
        }
      }
    };
  }
};

for (let number of num) {
  alert(number); // 1, then 2, 3, 4, 5
}
```

What i want to understand is why i don't get this statement {done:true, value:this.current}?

Comment: Cause for...of unpacks the objects, exposes the value and terminates when `.done` is true.

Comment: Because that's how the [iterator protocol](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Iteration_protocols) is defined to work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`for..of` iterates over iterables by *automatically extracting* the sequential `value` properties returned by the `.next()` method, until `done` evaluates to `true`. The expression assigned to the variable in the `for..of` loop is the `.value` of the object returned by the current iteration.

If you called the `[Symbol.iterator]` manually, with your object or with any other iterable object, you'd see the object with a `done` property instead:

```js
let num = {
  from: 1,
  to: 5,

  [Symbol.iterator]() {
    return {
      current: this.from,
      last: this.to,
      next() {
        if (this.current <= this.last) {
          return {
            done: false,
            value: this.current++
          };
        } else {
          return {
            done: true
          };
        }
      }
    };
  }
};

const it = num[Symbol.iterator]();
console.log(it.next(), it.next(), it.next());
```

```js
const arr = [0, 1, 2];

const it = arr[Symbol.iterator]();
console.log(it.next(), it.next(), it.next());
```

Comment: What if i used a normal object that has the key **to** and **from**.                                `let num = {to:1,from:5};`

Comment: Normal objects aren't iterable, so they can't be iterated over with `for..of`.